# How to get a "wave" effect using SceneKit?

Tags: swift, scenekit

Need some help or minds, how to get this effect in SceneKit?

I'm using the `NSConstraint` to develop it but with no success...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to develop this `wave` effect is to use a Secondary Editor (Actions tab) in Xcode.

You have to create 6 cubes, position them equidistantly along x axis. For each cube you need to apply a `Move` action and then assign `+3` and `-3` value to `Y` parameter respectively in `Attributes` inspector. Then select both clips (for each cube) on the timeline and choose `Create Loop` and then choose `infinite` sign in RMB context menu.

For each next cube in a queue you need to move a `Move` action's clip in time. Like this:

[image]

Or use the following code for each cube (do not forget to assign time offset):

```
boxUno.geometry = SCNBox()
boxUno.position.x = -10 //initial position along x axis
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxUno)

let up_Uno = SCNVector3(x: -10, y: 3, z: 0)
let stay_Uno = SCNVector3(x: -10, y: 0, z: 0)
let down_Uno = SCNVector3(x: -10, y: -3, z: 0)
let moveUp_Uno = SCNAction.move(to: up_Uno, duration: 0.25)
let zero_Uno = SCNAction.move(to: stay_Uno, duration: 0.25)
let moveDown_Uno = SCNAction.move(to: down_Uno, duration: 0.25)

boxUno.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.sequence([moveUp_Uno,
                                                             zero_Uno,
                                                             moveDown_Uno,
                                                             zero_Uno])))

//boxDos.position.x = -5
//boxTres.position.x = 0
//boxCuatro.position.x = 5
//boxCinco.position.x = 10
//boxSeis.position.x = 15
```